# How to troubleshoot a bash script called by a python script called by a program?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, python, debugging, error-handling

I have to troubleshoot this bash script  called by a python script called by a program, all run in Ubuntu 18.04.

The python script and the program are black boxes. The only information I have is that they work fine, and the python script only fails when it calls the bash script because the script itself fails.

The bash script is very simple and works fine on its own, but fails whenever called from this script, which leads me to believe there is some sort of permissions error. The problem is, I need to find a way to get the error message it gives when it fails. How can I get that information in this situation?

Putting `set -x` and `set -v` does not spit out any information to the terminal when the bash script is run from the python script.

Here is the contents of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" >> /scripts/vomit
mv $1/*.mp4 .
```

The problem line is `mv $1/*.mp4`. If I comment out that line, the script works when called from the python script that is called by the program. I just don't know *why* the mv line is failing.

Comment: Is it Linux or macOS?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does the variable `$1` expand to a relative or absolute file path?  If it is a relative file path, does the Python script know where it is supposed to be run from?

Comment: What is the value of `$1`? Since it's used unquoted, it would be split on whitespaces and undergo filename globbing. Does it specify a directory in the current working directory of the script that actually exists?

Comment: The value is '/var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation/5b64bdbe09fdefcc3004c987f22f163ca846f1ea-1574708322765/'. Believe I've tested with $1 in quotes, but re-testing. Recall that the bash script works fine if I run it on its own

Comment: And the files (if they exist) are not copied to the current directory of the script (do you know where this is?)?

Comment: The files exist and are not copied to the current directory of the script, correct. Re-running with quotes around $1 still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) command to debug a program with its all child processes.

For the new process:

```
strace -f command
```

For the existing process:

```
strace -fp PID
```

If you don't know your process id (as it's run too quickly), you can add `sleep 20` at the beginning of your shell script, so you've time to find its PID via `ps wuax | grep bash` then use above command with found PID.

To filter output use `-e`. To save into the file use `-o`. To increase size of messages, use `-s`. For more help, run: `man strace`.

For better formatting, see: [How to parse strace in shell into plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557017/55075)

---

Here is the practical example. Given the following `myscript.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "$1"
```

I've run the following command:

```
strace -f -e trace=execve,read,write -s1000 bash -x ./myscript.sh foo bar
```

which produced the following output:

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-x", "./myscript.sh", "foo", "bar"], [/* 41 vars */]) = 0
...
read(3, "#!/bin/bash -x\necho \"$1\"\n", 80) = 25
read(255, "#!/bin/bash -x\necho \"$1\"\n", 25) = 25
write(2, "+ echo foo\n", 11+ echo foo
)            = 11
write(1, "foo\n", 4foo
)                    = 4
read(255, "", 25)                       = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Having trouble formatting this. If the actual command that kicks off the program is bbb-record --rebuild 5b64bdbe09fdefcc3004c987f22f163ca846f1ea-1574708322765, how do I fit that into this strace command?

Comment: @Sidereal `strace -f bbb-record --rebuild 5b64bdbe09fdefcc3004c987f22f163ca846f1ea-1574708322765`

Comment: strace doesn't seem to follow the full thread of things that occur, which unfortunately doesn't help in this scenario.

Comment: `-f` follows all processes as a result of the fork, vfork and clone system calls, maybe the script is triggered using some different method.

Comment: @Sidereal Another way: add `sleep 20` to your bash script to give you some time, run `ps wuax | grep bash`, find its PID and try `strace -fp PID`.

Comment: I would add the flag `-o /tmp/strace.log` to the strace command to have its output go to a file. In particular, look for an `exec` to the name of the bash script to make sure it is being called.

Comment: I got strace to work, thank you. Now the problem is deciphering its output...

Comment: Just an FYI that I am running strace on the PID of the bash script itself.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is shown on the terminal, you can redirect output into the file, e.g.

For your entire script (all output) into the file (change it in Python):

```
./script.sh &> output.log
```

For the single command:

```
mv -v $1/*.mp4 . 2> errors.log
```

Also consider adding `set -x` or using `#!/bin/bash -x`.

---

To redirect all stdout and stderr to the file, see: [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20564208/55075), which is:

```
# Close STDOUT file descriptor
exec 1<&-
# Close STDERR FD
exec 2<&-

# Open STDOUT as $LOG_FILE file for read and write.
exec 1<> output.log

# Redirect STDERR to STDOUT
exec 2>&1
```